# Many-to-many relation in Doctrine2 leads to duplication error in migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I have made two Doctrine2 entities in my project which is based on the Symfony2 framework. This entities has many-to-many relation.
There are my models:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="first")
 */
class First
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var Second[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Second", cascade={"detach"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="first_to_second",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="second_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * )
     */
    private $seconds;

    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="second")
 */
class Second
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var First[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\First", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="first_to_second",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="second_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * )
     */
    private $firsts;

    ...
}
```

When I try to make migration

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migration:diff
```

there is an error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
> The table with name 'first_to_second' already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field definitions are wrong. You should define the `JoinTable` only one side (the owning side) of the relation and define which side is which by `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_groups")
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Group
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="groups")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

> #### 5.9.1. Owning and Inverse Side on a ManyToMany association
>
> For Many-To-Many associations you can chose which entity is the owning and which the inverse side. There is a very simple semantic rule to decide which side is more suitable to be the owning side from a developers perspective. You only have to ask yourself, which entity is responsible for the connection management and pick that as the owning side.

Comment: So can I write this in the First entity?
`code
/** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Second", cascade={"remove"}, mappedBy="firsts") */
private $seconds;
`

Comment: Nope `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Second", cascade={"remove"}, inversedBy="firsts")` and `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Second", cascade={"remove"}, mappedBy="seconds")` and remove the `JoinTable` from the `Second`. The linked documentation explains it well, read it please.